# Чем является каталог "storage/modification" в OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, кэширование

Недавно присел на OpenCart 2+ и установил плагин, который не выполнил свою функцию на 100%. Пришлось править. В ходи правки я заметил, что *.tpl файлы изменяемые мной не изменяются. Были подозрения на кэш. В результате нашел каталог `"storage/modification"` и в нем были эти файлы. Я их поправил и я счастлив.

**Вопрос:** Что это за папка? Она хранит данные как временные файлы(кэш) либо можно там править файлы и жить спокойной?

Еще нюанс - эти файлы отличаются. Есть подозрение из-за каких-то модулей. 
Спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В эту папку записываются изменённые ocMod-расширениями файлы - контроллеры, модули, стили - любые. Когда вы ставите какое-либо ocMod-расширение, в целевые файлы шаблона/движка вносятся правки, необходимые для работы этого расширения. Но что бы не создавать их каждый раз при запросе магазина, опенкарт записывает их в папку system/storage/modification, не затрагивая таким образом файлы оригиналы. Далее каждый роут опенкарта сперва смотрит в эту папку и если находит там файлы, то работает с ними а если нет, то использует файлы-оригиналы.

Comment: т.е эти файлы можно менять? А если расширения удаляется, тогда и файлы с ним соответственно?

Comment: @Node_pro Менять можно. Но после каждого обновления кеша в админке(не клиентского а кеша опенкарта) ваши изменения будут затираться, т.к. вся процедура создания модифицированных файлов будет происходить заново. Меняйте файлы-оригиналы и сносите кеши. Так ваши изменения будут оставаться и в модифицированных файлах. И да, удаление расширения ведёт к удалению модифицированных им файлов.

Comment: Кнопка очистки кэша кстати не помогает его очистить (opencart 2), времено переименовал ту директорию, чтобы он не использовался